# Angular 6 unit test rxjs 6 operator tap unit test interceptor

Tags: rxjs, operators, interceptor, angular6, rxjs6

Since I update my code to the new Rxjs 6, I had to change the interceptor code like this:

auth.interceptor.ts:

```
...
return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // do stuff with response if you want
        }
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            this.authService.loginRedirect();
          }
          return observableThrowError(this.handleError(error));
        }
      })
    );
```

and I'm not able to test the rxjs operators "tap" and "catchError".

Actually i'm only able to test if pipe is called:

```
it('should intercept and handle request', () => {
    const req: any = {
      clone: jasmine.createSpy('clone')
    };

    const next: any = {
      handle: () => next,
      pipe: () => next
    };

    spyOn(next, 'handle').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(next, 'pipe').and.callThrough();

    interceptor.intercept(req, next);

    expect(next.handle).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(next.pipe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(req.clone).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Any help is apreciated on how to spy the rxjs operators

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you shouldn't be testing that operators were called like this at the first place.

Operators in both RxJS 5 and RxJS 6 are just functions that only "make recipe" how the chain is constructed. This means that checking if `tap` or `catchError` were called doesn't tell you anything about it's functionality or whether the chain works at all (it might throw an exception on any value and you won't be able to test it).

Since you're using RxJS 6 you should rather test the chain by sending values through. This is well documented and pretty easy to do https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md

In your case you could do something like this:

```
const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  // some how assert the two objects are equal
  // e.g. with chai `expect(actual).deep.equal(expected)`
});

// This test will actually run *synchronously*
testScheduler.run(({ cold }) => {
  const next = {
    handle: () => cold('-a-b-c--------|'),
  };
  const output = interceptor.intercept(null, next);

  const expected = '   ----------c---|'; // or whatever your interceptor does
  expectObservable(output).toBe(expected);
});
```

I think you'll get the point what this does...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, in fact, this type of test it's the most simple, i got the ones that test the 401 redirection. Maybe it does not make sense now this test. I will check your link to understand better that approach. Thank you very much again

Comment: It's not actually working for me, I too have similar test case.  It's not getting called either catchError  nor tap, I tried with hot and cold with '#' and '|' values.
I followed given documentation.

Comment: @ayyappamaddi If you don't show your code no one can help you.

Comment: Marble testing link is broken - here is the corresponding Angular page - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/internal-marble-tests